# If $Z = X + Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are two independent, uniform random variables, then what is the conditional distribution of $X | Z$?

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

So I have been struggling with this question for a while. Suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed over an interval $(a, b)$ and $Y$ is uniformly distributed over $(-\sigma, \sigma)$, $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Consider a random variable $Z = X + Y$. What would be the *conditional* distribution of $X | Z$, i.e. $F_{X|Z}(x)$?

I know that $F_X(x) = \frac{x - a}{b-a}$ and $F_y(y) = \frac{y + \sigma}{2\sigma}$ but I am having trouble figuring out $F_{X|Z}(x)$. Could anyone help me? My gut says that $X|Z$ *should* be uniformly distributed over $(Z - \sigma, Z + \sigma)$ but I can't figure out how to prove this.

Comment: The pdf of $X|Z$ is 
\begin{align*}
f_{X|Z}(x|z) &= \frac{f_{X,Z}(x,z)}{f_Z(z)}\\
&=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y=z-x)}{f_Z(z)}\\
&=\frac{f_{X}(x)f_Y(y=z-x)}{f_Z(z)}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

$X|Z$ can't, in general, be uniformly distributed over $(z-\sigma,z+\sigma)$ because there are values of $z$ such that $(z-\sigma,z+\sigma)$ is not a subset of $(a,b)$. (Note that $Z$ is a random variable, $z$ is real number drawn from its distribution. $Z-\sigma$ is not a real number, because $Z$ is a random variable, not a real number. A random variable over the real numbers is different from a real number.)

Draw a rectangle with horizontal dimension $(a,b)$ and vertical $(-\sigma,\sigma)$. Then draw diagonal lines with slope $-1$ in the rectangle. Each diagonal line represents a constant value of $z$. For a particular $z_0$, $X$ will be uniformly distributed along the horizontal extension of the corresponding diagonal line. To find $X|Z$, you have to take several cases depending on whether $z<a$, $z>b$, $z<-\sigma$, $z>\sigma$.

Comment: I see. I realize that for $z \in (a - \sigma, a)$ and $z \in(b, b + \sigma)$, the cases will be different. Clearly, for $z = a - \sigma$, $x = a$ and likewise for $z = b + \sigma$, the only possible value for $x = b$. What I am more curious about is the distribution for more intermediary values (mainly $z \in (a + \sigma, b - \sigma)$). Would it be uniform over $(z - \sigma, z+ \sigma)$ then?

Comment: @MAdnanM The conditional distribution of $X$ when $z$ falls in the intermediary region will be uniform but the lower and upper limits of this uniform distribution will depend on whether the rectangle is "tall" or "wide". If the rectangle is wide, then the intermediary region is $(a+\sigma, b-\sigma)$ [as you've indicated] and the conditional distribution of $X$ is uniform from $z-\sigma$ to $z+\sigma$; but if the rectangle is tall, then the intermediary region is $(b-\sigma, a+\sigma)$ [note the endpoints are reversed] and the conditional distribution of $X$ is uniform from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: @grand_chat, thank you! I didn't realize that the shape of the rectangle mattered in this. To clarify, I'm assuming that $\sigma$ is very small compared to $b-a$ so the rectangle is "wide". It's good to know that the conditional distribution of $X$ is uniform over $(z-\sigma,z+\sigma)$ for intermediate values of $z$ but I'm still struggling to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can show that the conditional density of $X$ given $X+Y$ is uniform by applying the change of variables formula. Define the transformation $(W,Z):=(X,X+Y)$. The joint density of $(W,Z)$ is
$$
f_{W,Z}(w,z)=f_{X,Y}(x(w,z),y(w,z)) = f_{X,Y}(w, z-w).\tag1$$ (Check that the Jacobian of the transformation is $1$.) Since the joint density of $(X,Y)$ is
$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=I_{(a,b)}(x)I_{(-\sigma,\sigma)}(y),\tag2$$ write (1) as
$$
f_{W,Z}(w,z)=I_{(a,b)}(w)I_{(-\sigma,\sigma)}(z-w).\tag3
$$
Plotting in the $(w,z)$-plane, we find the density (3) is uniform over a skewed diamond shape. In fact, for fixed $z$ the value of (3) is zero unless $a<w<b$ and $z-\sigma<w<z+\sigma$, in which case the value of (3) is $1$. The key observation is that for fixed $z$, the expression (3), when nonzero, is *constant* as a function of $w$. This means that when we divide (3) by the marginal density $f_Z(z)$ (note we don't even have to compute the value!), the resulting conditional density $f_{W\mid Z}(w\mid z)$ remains constant as a function of $w$.